# laravel doesn't use published views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view, laravel-blade

For my Laravel 5.5 project I used filemanager package ([elfinder-laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder) ) with published and adapted blade views. After awhile I found that default views are used from package folder:

```
/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder/resources/views
```

instead of published views:

```
/resources/views/vendor/elfinder
```

I tried to republish views, clear views and cache. But nothing helps, it still uses default package views.

Views in /resources/views/vendor/elfinder exist.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: did you publish the config files? ex `php artisan vendor:publish --provider='Barryvdh\Elfinder\ElfinderServiceProvider' --tag=config`

Answer (score 2):

Try to edit the service provider file to be like that :

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom($this->app->resourcePath('views/vendor/elfinder'), 'elfinder');
}
```

It is forces the file to use this directory as main view directory instead of changing it.

Comment: please where is the service provider file  located?

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, but you have to set in the

```php
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/views', 'courier');
```

the same package name as in the

```php
$this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/../resources/views' => resource_path('views/vendor/courier'),
    ]);
```

(notice both times the courier)

See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages#overriding-package-views

Comment: please where is the service provider located?